# How to create platform for double data check

Tags: database, duplicates

I have looked around Stackoverflow but I couldn't find what I looked for.

**Problem:**
I need a platform - it may be a database or something else - where I can store data in the background. Different people can check - for example a postal zip - whether this postal zip has already been added into the database.

Right now I am using an Excel Spreadsheet which highlights the postal zip when entered. The problem is, everybody can see each postal zip that has been entered, and I don't want them to see it.

So, I want something on the front where people can enter the postal zip and then it checks whether the postal zip has been entered before and gives an error if it has. If it doesn't, it must be entered into the "database".

**Question:**
Does anybody know the best way to setup something like this?

Comment: Have you thought about creating a form in Microsoft Access, where the user can input a postal code, and when they hit the submit button can insert the value, plus perform checks you need. It's easier to make an access for then to create a windows application, for example.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Yes, I have thought about that. But the problem for me is that it needs to be a web application. Our company can only give the item once per postal zip, so to avoid giving items to the same customer we need something to check if he/she already has taken it. Also it is spread around the country and different people from different computers will need to use something like this. I don't think they all want to install MS Access or purchase one..

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a standard behavior in just about any web application (using just about any technology) using any database as a backend. This includes PHP, ASP.net, Node.JS on the server side, anything on the front end, and DB technologies like MySQL, PostgresSql and Sql Server on the backend.

Using these, you can set up a CRUD page (Create, Read, Update, Delete) for postal codes, and allow for validation that will check whether data exists or not before allowing insertion.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I thought that the question I asked was a bit of a beginner question, but so am I. The only thing I can work with is Wordpress for now and a bit of HTML.. Is there something simple that you can recommend me to setup something like this? Because something that looks so simple, became something hard.. (a link or a tutorial somewhere will get me on the right track I guess)

Comment: If it is just an in-the-office thing then MS Access might be ok like @pops suggested. If you need web access, then anything that I mentioned would be good. Something like this is routine if you know what you are doing, but if you don't then it can be daunting to even do this. If you are serious about it, I would recommend looking into taking a short online course on building web applications, and use the framework/platform that they teach you (all have pluses and minuses), but need to know more about your requirements before recommending).

Comment: As I responded to @pops I "think" it needs to be a web application. Something simple that is accesable for every person on his on PC without installing software which he/she has to pay for. You have suggested several things like PHP, Ask.net and many more. If this is easy for someone who knows what he is doing, maybe it would be a better idea to find someone like that and pay them in return.. But it's not a market place around here, and I do like to put some effort into learning this. So.. if there is a good guideline I could use I will take it.